# Slowing down 3-speed ceiling fan

Tags: capacitor, motor, speed

I have a 120 V, 60 Hz, 3-speed ceiling fan. The capacitor is a 4-wire one with the following value for capacitor E183963 CBB61:
5 μF +/-5% 250 VAC = Yellow
5 μF +/-5% 250 VAC = Purple
4.5 μF +/-5% 280 VAC = Gray
Common = Black

I would like to slow down the low speed only to about 1/4 to 1/2 the current speed. Can I do this by switching out the capacitor with a different value for the low speed?

Comment: Bigger capacitor, smaller current. The motor may not start. You need to start with bigger current and reduce current at move.

Comment: A better way to do this is with a thyristor speed control *designed for motors*. Caution: not all motors are compatible with speed controls.